# Python networkx, how to change node size?

Tags: python, networkx

I have a simple configuration model, and I would like to change the size of nodes in the graph.

My code is:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
hosts = 100
H=nx.configuration_model([2]*hosts)
nx.draw_random(H)
```

[image]

I tried including node_size but this is undefined and I receive the error:

```
TypeError: configuration_model() got an unexpected keyword argument 'node_size'
```

How do I change the size of my nodes?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `node_size` parameter in `draw_random`

```
nx.draw_random(H, node_size=100)
```

[image]